# Spring: ModelMap attributes are not shown in jsp

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

my data, which I try to pass from my controller to the view is apparently ignored. The console doesn't output any errors. Can somebody point me to the apparently obvious mistake I did?

**Controller**

```
@RequestMapping("/notes")
public String index(ModelMap model) {
    String test = "Hello Felix";
    model.addAttribute("hello", test);

    return "notes";
}
```

**View**

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Notes</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>${hello}</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

**HTML Source**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Notes</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1></h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return the model, something like the following should work:

```
Map model = ...
model.put(name, value);
return new ModelAndView(view, model);
```